# How to add a route configuration separator to dropdown menu?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to add a separator (such as "---" or a solid line) to the drop-down navigation in my project. I am using route config as follows to construct the navigation - please see below for comment where the separator should go.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Main", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

routes.MapNavigationRoute<MyController>("Dropdown", c => c.Index(), "", false, true, "")
                .AddChildRoute<MyController>("Option 1", c => c.Option1(), "", true, true, "")
                // how to add a separator here???
                .AddChildRoute<MyController>("Option 2", c => c.Option2(), "", true, true, "")
                ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a built in one.  We manually create our separators.  In your case,  something like this

```
.AddChildRoute<MyController>("--------", "", "", true, true, "")
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for something more built it. Do you have an example of how you would create the separator manually (assuming you are routeconfig) Thanks

Comment: I haven't put a dropdown in a routeconfig before.  We use separators in context menus and dropdowns.  Basically add an item with dashes and set the value to "" so that when it is selected it doesn't do anything.